# Collecting information from menu items printed from database (including dynamic creation of Quantity drop down and add to cart)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to link the dynamically created quantity drop down list to it's respective add to cart button.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT Course_name as name, Calories, Remarks, PictureID, Price, Ingredients, Description, Days FROM I_MAIN_COURSE";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    print "<ul>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $n=$row['name'];
            $c=$row['Calories'];
            $i=$row['Ingredients'];
            $p=$row['Price'];
            $r=$row['Remarks'];
            $d=$row['Days'];
            $de=$row['Description'];
            $_SESSION["name"]=$n;
        print "<li>";
        print "<p>Name:".$n."</p>";
        print "<p>Calories: ".$c." cal</p>";
        print "<p>Price: ".$p."</p>";
        print "<p>Available Day: ".$d."</p>";
        print "<p>Ingredients: ".$i."</p>";
        print "<p>Description: ".$de."</p>";
        print "<p>Remarks: ".$r."</p>";
        ?>
        Quantity:
            <select class="lol" name = "quantity">
            <option value = "0">0</option>
            <option value = "1">1</option>
            <option value = "2">2</option>
            <option value = "3">3</option>
            <option value = "4">4</option>
            <option value = "5">5</option>
            <option value = "6">6</option>
            <option value = "7">7</option>
            <option value = "8">8</option>
            <option value = "9">9</option>
            <option value = "10">10</option>
            </select>
            <button class="food" value="<?php echo $n ?>" > Add to Cart</button>    
            </li>
    <?php
    $count++;
    }
    print "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you saying that when you select the quantity from the drop-down, when you click submit, you need to be able to tell which product has the quantity selected?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you mean you are not sure how to differentiate the quantity dropdowns from one cart item to the next. To do that you need to get the `id` *(or whatever your unique auto incrementing column name is)* of the item from your database and array the `select` input so your SQL should be something like:

```
//add ---------v
$sql = "SELECT id, Course_name as name, Calories, Remarks, PictureID, Price, Ingredients, Description, Days FROM I_MAIN_COURSE";
```

Then add that id to the select:

```
<select class="lol" name = "quantity[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]">
```

You would get this when you submit:

```
Array
    (
        [quantity] => Array
            (
                [123] => 3
            )
    )
```